# Splot triangles from binary data file

Tags: gnuplot, binary-data

I have a binary files that have `binary format='%float32%float32%float32'`, having D3 points (`using 1:2:3`). Originally logically points grouped by 3 to form triangles. I want to plot just legs of triangles as a lines using `with lines`. In ASCII data file I can make so-called *datablocks* by adding an empty line between triples of lines, but in binary I can't. I want to break a chain of lines at every three points to form at least V-like parts of triangle contours.

Is there an option to make `gnuplot` to treat a triples of points as separate *datablocks*?

Is there another option to `splot` the data as (maybe) a solid triangles?

Comment: Can you provide some data which can be used for testing and illustration?

Comment: base64 encoded data: `base64 -d <<< 'E3FVP33BBzxTg+Q+DfV/wH8NgMD5/3+/1/J/wAAAgD+1qf6/aNS0M0YAgMAAAIBA//+fQAEAoMCc7yLAF+E9wBMAgMAAAADAjOWONwAAgMD//39A' >file.dat`. There is a header to skip: 12 bytes. For `binary` it is `skip=12`. `md5sum` is `2157773fa119c2c7d87403f418193983`.

Comment: thanks. Just that I understand correctly: you have a series of floats "f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9...", where "f1f2f3" and "f4f5f6" and "f7f8f9" represent 3 3D-points of a triangle and you basically want to skip every 3rd point?

Comment: Format is as you said. But I want to plot all triangles. No (except header) data have to be be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure whether I'm fully on the right track.
The following code writes your binary data into a table and makes groups of 3 datapoints for a triangle, inserting an empty line and then shifted by one for the next triangle.
So, So from the points `p1=f1,f2,f3`; `p2=f4,f5,f6`; `p3=f7,f8,f9`; ... it creates the triangles `p1p2p3p1 p2p3p4p2 p3p4p5p3` (space=empty line).

Certainly, not very (memory) efficient, but maybe this gets closer to your final goal.
Check `help pm3d` and `help hidden3d`, where you might get some additional information.
I very much hope that there is a better approach.

**Code:** (assuming the binary file `'myBinary.bin'`, not sure whether I decoded your ASCII string correctly)

```
# plot binary data
reset session

# put binary data into a datablock
set table $Data
    plot 'myBinary.bin' u 1:2:3 binary format='%float32%float32%float32' skip=12 w table
unset table

# separate each triangle by an empty line
set print $Data2
    do for [i=1:|$Data|-2] {
        print $Data[i]
        print $Data[i+1]
        print $Data[i+2]
        print $Data[i]
        print ""          # insert empty line
    }
set print
set pm3d hidden3d
set view 40, 24

splot $Data2 u 1:2:3 w pm3d notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much! There is a need in one another `print ""` to make two separate triangles instead of triangle strip. Really example data consists of header + 18 floats. Thank you. Didn't know about `set table`.

Comment: glad to hear. I hope somebody else will come up with a better solution.

Comment: strange... If I add a second empty line, nothing will be plotted.

Comment: This is because of `pm3d`.